# Set an Activity as the initial activity of an android app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

In my new android sudio project I created two activities. The first is the MainActivity and the second is called SecondActivity. The second is more like a sort of menù. Logically, when the app starts, SecondActivity must appear as first.

In the manifest I declared both the activities but I don't know how to declare them correctly so that SecondActivity appears as the first activity in the application after I loaded it on my Android device.

This is my project's manifest :

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"> </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">` to `<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">` and second activity change to Main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this, my friend

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"> 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options...

1) Move the intent filter.

2) Switch  the `android:name` property since ordering does not matter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"> <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter></activity>
</application>
```

The intent-filter tag let you choose trough the action wich activity will be the main.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the intent filters to the second activity like so:

```
...

<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

...
```

The parts between the intent-filter tags (`<intent-filter>` and `</intent-filter>`) tell Android that this activity should be used when the launcher icon of your app is pressed (i.e. the initial activity).